# Handle null value in view in mvc in lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, lambda

I tried to handle null value when my below lambda expression in view with multiple where clause comparing dates and time but it doesn;t get handled.

```
@Model.TopicTime
    .Where(x =>
        x.LectureStartDate == Convert.ToDateTime(@ViewBag.MinDate1) &&
        x.LectureStartTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss") == @ViewBag.MinTime1 &&
        x.LectureStartTime.AddHours(1).ToString("hh:mm:s") == @ViewBag.MinTime2)
    .FirstOrDefault()
    .TopicName;
```

Handling through null value but still doesn't work gives me error as

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   App_Web_nbl342dp.dll but was not handled in user code

```
@(Model.TopicTime
    .Where(x => 
        x.LectureStartDate == Convert.ToDateTime(@ViewBag.MinDate1) &&
        x.LectureStartTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss") == @ViewBag.MinTime1 &&
        x.LectureStartTime.AddHours(15).ToString("hh:mm:ss") == @ViewBag.MinTime2)
    .FirstOrDefault()
    .TopicName  == null ? "" : 
  Model.TopicTime
      .Where(x => 
          x.LectureStartDate == Convert.ToDateTime(@ViewBag.MinDate1) &&
          x.LectureStartTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss") == @ViewBag.MinTime1 &&                                        
          x.LectureStartTime.AddHours(1).ToString("hh:mm:ss") == @ViewBag.MinTime2)
      .FirstOrDefault().TopicName
)
```

Comment: could you please rewrite your post to the stackoverflow readable format?

Comment: So are you trying to determine if `TopicName` is null? It's possible that `LectureStartTime` is null, which is what `FirstOrDefault()` would return, thus breaking the expression.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to determine if TopicName is null or not. But ya, u are right LectureStartTime is getting null in it so how should i resolve it, break expressions or how?  Thanks in advance

Comment: I just want to check topics conducted in where clause as date and lecturestart time and lecture end time

Answer (score 0):

Well, while you are at null checks - it is also possible that @Model is null.

The real problem here is that your underlying data structure is not well defined. Considering that all you want is to display TopicName, you would be better off doing all the checks in controller and then in view just display @Model.TopicName, rather than embedding passing variables in ViewBag and embedding logic in View.

Comment: kape123 . No Model is not null, In where clause if where condition is null then it doesn't allow me to handle null. If value doesn't exist , then how to handle null value